# RegExp Look for part but exclude If

Tags: python, regex

Right so RegExp is fairly new to me and its still puzzling me. Anyway I managed to look for almost all the names I want to but now I have to look for names that have specific part of world in it but exclude if there is another one next to it.

So basically

Looks for `"Cat"` however if there is `"Dog"` then exclude this string so a:

```
CatBlablablaDog = exclude
blablaCatBlabla = include
Dog_blabla_Cat = exclude
```

Atm I'm using this to look for my names 
`'*Cat*'` I guess I could also use `/*.Cat/` or something similar to that(I cant remember exact symbols I have it somewhere written)
So what do I have to add to exclude the Dog objects? (I code in Python)

If I cant do it this way maybe I can loop through objects and look for other names than Dog. Then iterate through the new non dog names for Cat names? Which mean what do I type to not look for Dog name? :)

Thanks, bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an alternative, non-regex solution to [@Rohit Jain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975579/586621)

Single line without regular expressions (playing with it in the [repl](/questions/tagged/repl)):

```py
>>> (lambda s: 'cat' in s and 'dog' not in s)("CatBlablablaDog".lower())
False
>>> (lambda s: 'cat' in s and 'dog' not in s)("blablaCatBlabla".lower())
True
>>> (lambda s: 'cat' in s and 'dog' not in s)("Dog_blabla_Cat".lower())
False
```

Using a more formal function of some sorts:

```py
def findExclude(string, search_str, exclude_str):
    string = string.lower()
    return search_str in string and exclude_str not in string

print findExclude("CatBlablablaDog", 'cat', 'dog')
print findExclude("blablaCatBlabla", 'cat', 'dog')
print findExclude("Dog_blabla_Cat", 'cat', 'dog')
```

Comment: This would work but I dont have the initial list of strings.I can look for them but afterwards they just £53263471 and not actual names. Not sure how to convert them back to strings tho. Will have to see if I can get this to work. If I can get them to be strings then I could possibly use this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use negative look-ahead:

```
^(?!.*dog).*cat.*$
```

It will first test that there is no `dog` further in the string. If negative look-ahead succeeds, then it goes on to match the string containing `cat`. You might want to enable ignore case in it using `(?i)` flag.

In python, you can also use `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
>>> import re
>>> ignorecase = re.compile(r'(?i)(?!.*dog).*cat.*')
>>> print ignorecase.match("CatBlablablaDog")
None
>>>
>>> print ignorecase.match("blablaCatBlabla")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x956b090>
>>>
>>> print ignorecase.match("Dog_blabla_Cat")
None
```

Comment: So basically he will select cat object if there is nowhere in the string dog? I'm failing to make it work :( Maybe its the program issue rather than code. Might need to email vred support wreh.
Thanks for help!

Comment: @Dariusz. Do you want to retrieve `cat`? Or just want to see if the string matches.

Comment: I want to match string of object. Basically name match. I can select node by name using regexp or select all(select all will not work). I want to select using names but I have to exclude objects that have more complex names. Since they like dummy objects and I dont need them. - cant delete them either. Trevor Senior would work if I could get strings after listing objects but at the moment I cant.