# Regex includes part of string but excludes another part of strig

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find out how someone hacked on of my clients' sites. I am searching the log files using `^(?!.*404).*194\.226.*$` to try and find a line in a log file where someone whose IP address starts with 194.226 was accessing the server that did not result in a 404.

A typical line in the log file is `194.226.xx.xx - - [18/Feb/2014:01:45:10 +0100] "GET /tikiwiki/tiki-graph_formula.php?w=1&h=1&s=1&min=1&max=2&f[]=x.tan.phpinfo()&t=png&title=http://www.google.com/humans.txt? HTTP/1.0" 404 84403 "-" "-" 163 84852`

I assume the 404 near the end of the line is a 404 not found as it follows the HTTP/1.0 response.

It is important that the 194.226 IS in the line, but 404 is NOT in the line. From research here [RegExp Look for part but exclude If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975560/regexp-look-for-part-but-exclude-if), I came up with the above line. It is either not working or it is not found. I have no way of knowing which one though, as the log file is 2188MB in size.

My question: Is the regex correct?

Comment: What tool/language are you using ? `^$` means start & end of *string*. You might want to use the `m` modifier to "convert" it to start & end of *line*. But it really depends on the tool/language you're using.

Comment: Hi HamZa, I am using UltraEdit which uses Perl compatible regular expressions. I have, however, downloaded another large log file since this post, and did find that it actually works. So - for those interested, I found this with the query, showing a possible way the hacker hacks the password: `194.226.xx.xx - - [18/Feb/2014:01:34:03 +0100] "GET /index.php?page=../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00 HTTP/1.0" 200 83670 "-" "-" 97 84112`

Comment: Running that URL myself on the site does not return any bad info to me, so that is not the case, but it could've been :-)

Comment: It seems the attacker tried to exploit an LFI vulnerability. You might want to hire a professional pentester or try to figure it out yourself. There are some great resources about websecurity. You might checkout "OWASP". You might also start from [here](https://www.pentesterlab.com/exercises/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you move

```
^194\.226\.((?!404).)*$
```

demo : http://regex101.com/r/eM5bR8

Comment: Although HamZa's comments on my question helped me a lot, you answered the actual question first, so I will accept your answer. Thanks, aelor!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the regular expression is correct as long as you can be sure, that 404 is not part of the IP-adress

Comment: While 404 can be part of an [IP address](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/3/inet_addr/), it is safe to assume that log file outputs the dotted-decimal notation.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
(?!.*404).*\b194\.226\b.*
```

Also, you'll need to use multiline flag, so that it matches all those.